# Trying to make a GET request from localhost:8080 to localhost:3000 but I get a cors error, and installing cors on my node.js server doesn't fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

So I'm trying to make an axios GET request to my Node.js/Express.js `localhost:3000` server from my front-end app on `localhost:8080` and I understand why I am getting a CORS error. What I don't understand is why after I installed the `cors` npm package and used it as middleware on my Node.js/Express.js back-end, I still get the CORS error.

I did this inside the `app.js` file

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Then I still get the following error when I try to make a GET request from my front-end:

﻿

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/images' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Shouldn't me using the cors package solve this problem?

Comment: Did you fix your problem?  Share us a mvp. Cors error is very common and solution is always the same.

Comment: @JRichardsz Unfortunately I haven't yet and I'm still looking for solution. The answer below is not working for me, and I know that this is not the problem since I have another node.js/express project which uses the cors package the same way, and it works just fine. Once I figure it out, I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow cors to receive that origin. There's a good [good video about this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNtFSVU-YTI&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified). But adding the parameter origin to the cors() middleware should solve it.

```js
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:8000"
}));
```